# How would I fix this glitch in my (TweenMax) tween?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I got this stupid glitch in the linear tween when the birds fly from left to right (i.e. sometimes they freeze).

Live : http://tli-temp.heroku.com/
Code :

```
package tli {

  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.utils.Timer;
  import com.greensock.TweenMax;
  import com.greensock.easing.Linear;

public class Birds {

    private var birds:Array;

    public function Birds():void {
      birds = TLI.birds as Array;
      var i:uint = 4;
      while (i > 0) { new_bird(i); --i; }
    }

    private function new_bird(nr:uint):void {
      var b:Bird = new Bird();
      b.name = 'Bird nr.' + nr;
      b.scaleX = 0.23;
      b.scaleY = 0.23;
      b.x = -100;

      TLI.stage.addChild(b);

      birds.push(b);

      setTimeout(function():void {  tween_bird( birds[0] ); birds.shift()  }, rndm(5500, 500));
    }

    private function tween_bird(bird:Bird):void {
      bird.x = -100;
      bird.y = rndm(TLI.stage.stageHeight - TLI.sea.height - 80, 50);

      TweenMax.to( bird, rndm(55,35), {
        x: TLI.stage.stageWidth + 100, ease: Linear.easeNone,
        onComplete: tween_bird, onCompleteParams: [bird]
      });
    }

    private function rndm(max:uint, min:uint=0):uint {  return Math.floor( Math.random() * (max-min) ) + min }
}}
```

Anyone got an idea how I could fix this?

Comment: actually i had an error before any glithces: Error #2015: BitmapData Object is not valid.
at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
at flash.display::BitmapData()
at tli::Sky()
at TLI/init()

Comment: Hmm weird, I didn't have that error and I'm using a debugger player too. But thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: What be the glitch?  On first look, i'd say the timer plus TweenMax is overkill.  Maybe use one or the other.

Comment: Why is that overkill? And yeah, I should probably use the delay property now that I think of it.

Comment: @igor-milla So, I altered my code a bit, do you still get that error?

Comment: I don't get what the glitch is either could you describe what the intended behaviour is supposed to be

Comment: Well on my side, now and then the birds freeze. Only in the browser though.

Comment: I'm getting the same error that igor reported.

Comment: @lcid still the same ff 3.6 win with 10.2 debug player, if this help.  but in non debug player, it works fine

Comment: Just to clarify the issue, can you describe the "freeze". I'm not able to get the Birds to freeze completely, however, I am seeing a "hiccup" about every 10 seconds.

Comment: @Corey, it's the "hiccup" that's the problem ;)

Comment: @Icid, do you have any other processes running? I think this issue is affecting more than just the birds as the glow animation on the buttons will also briefly lock up simultaneously.

Comment: I’ve installed the latest debugger version and opened it in Firefox. Now I see the error. In Chrome and in the standalone debuggers I don’t get the error… Weird =/ Error seems to come from this line: ** var n:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sky_w, sky_h); **

Comment: @Corey, no I don't and yeah, it's probably affecting more than just the birds =) In the standalone Flash player it works just fine.. I don't get iiit <.<

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 var t:Timer = new Timer(wait_time, 1);
```

Creates a timer in the function scope.  When the function goes out of scope, the timer becomes a candidate for garbage collection.  It's possible the timer is garbage collected and the complete event never fires.

A setTimeout() call is safe, and probably does what you need.

Not sure if that's the problem you're seeing, but it is a problem you probably want to fix.

Comment: I prefer using TweenMax's delayedCall rather than setTimeout. It gives you a bit more flexibility and it's cleaner.

Comment: I don't believe that a running Timer with events referencing it is garbage collected.